# How to define an environment for a boxed and named theorem?

Tags: formatting, environments, theorems, amsthm, newtheorem

The environment below gives a boxed theorem with normal font (non italic text).

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage[tikz]{mdframed}
\usepackage{amsthm}

\newtheorem{thm}{Theorem}[section]

\newenvironment{thmm}
  {\begin{mdframed}\begin{thm}\normalfont}
  {\end{thm}\end{mdframed}}

\begin{document}

\section{Fisrt Section}

\begin{thmm} Statement without italic.
\end{thmm}

\end{document}
```

*Question:* How to define an environment for a boxed **and named** theorem with normal font?. In other words, how to define an envioremnt for the following code?

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage[tikz]{mdframed}
\usepackage{amsthm}

\newtheorem{thm}{Theorem}[section]

\begin{document}

\section{Fisrt Section}

\begin{mdframed} \begin{thm}[Name of the theorem]\normalfont Statement without italic.
\end{thm}\end{mdframed}

\end{document}
```

Comment: The `thmtools` package, which cooperates with  `amsthm` (as well as `ntheorem`) enables you to define an `mdframed` style key. See §§ 2.4 and 2.5 in the documentation.

Comment: If you want `\normalfont` and are using `amsthm`, why not use `\theoremstyle{definition}`?

Comment: @barbarabeeton Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you use `\tcolorboxenvironment` from the tcolorbox package. Then you can call the theorem with or without a heading as usual.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{amsthm}

\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem{thm}{Theorem}[section]

\tcolorboxenvironment{thm}{
  colback=white,
  sharp corners,
  boxrule=0.5pt,
  }

\begin{document}

\section{First Section}

\begin{thm}
Statement without italic.
\end{thm}

\begin{thm}[Some name]
Named statement without italic.
\end{thm}

\end{document}
```

[image: theorems]